# How to interface more complex shared library?

Tags: ruby, ctypes, ffi

I'm trying to dynamically call functions of external library on Linux/Unix system.

I have some success with `dl` library but only when primitive C types are used and arguments are passed by value:

```
require 'dl/import'
module LibM
  extend DL::Importer
  dlload 'libm.so'
  extern 'double sin(double)'
end

puts LibM.sin(3.14159265358979323846 / 2)    # 1.0
```

However how can be interfaced functions using more complex types like C structs or if arguments are pointers where results of the call are stored ?

```
module LibX11
  extend DL::Importer
  dlload 'libX11.so.6'
  extern 'Display *XkbOpenDisplay (char *display_name, int *event_rtrn, int *error_rtrn, int *major_in_out, int *minor_in_out, int *reason_rtrn)'
end
```

`Display` is a big struct, at `event_rtrn` is stored some result etc.

I've taken a look at [DL::CStructBuilder](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/dl/rdoc/DL/CStructBuilder.html) and it looks can do the job, but as the documentation is very brief and no working examples found I'm lost here how it has to be properly used.

I have to add standard Ruby 1.9 modules have to be used (if possible) as installation of additional gems on the target machine is prohibited.

Comment: Is the ffi gem an option? I've used that for plenty of apis involving structs being passed by reference/value

Comment: I'd wish ffi gem would be included in stock Ruby package as it looks much more mature then dl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing with interfacing with C libraries in this period (I am writing a [wrapper for libgtop](https://github.com/ProGNOMmers/gtop)), and I choosed to use [ffi](https://github.com/ffi/ffi), which is [quite well documented](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki) (although the documentation sometimes is a bit outdated) and above all its mailing list is full of people who give you an helping hand when you are in trouble.

So I propose you a solution which uses ffi:

```
require 'ffi'

module LibX11
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'libX11.so.6'

  # Display *XkbOpenDisplay (char *display_name, int *event_rtrn, int *error_rtrn, int *major_in_out, int *minor_in_out, int *reason_rtrn)
  attach_function :XkbOpenDisplay, [:pointer, :pointer, :pointer, :pointer, :pointer, :pointer], :pointer

end
```

Then you have to describe the `Display` struct layout, like written [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs):

```
class Display < FFI::Struct
  layout  :value,       :double,
          :other_value, :char,
          ...
end
```

And then you do something like this:

```
p1 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:char)
p2 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int)
p3 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int)
p4 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int)
p5 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int)
p6 = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int)

# write to pointer if needed, otherwise it is a null pointer
# p1.write_char('a')
# p2.write_int(1)
# ...

struct_pointer = LibX11.XkbOpenDisplay(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6)

# read the struct
struct = Display.new(display_struct_pointer)
p Hash[ s.members.map { |m| [ m, s[m] ] } ]
```

I didn't tested the code, but it should be roughly correct. Let me now if it isn't.

---

After some research about DL on ruby 2.0 I found that it is deprecated and replaced with fiddle, you would consider to use it rather than DL if you can't use FFI. Fiddle seems to be available for ruby 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 too

Comment: Great comprehensive information. I would either try to mimic it with `ruby/dl` or try to persuade a customer to allow installation of *ffi* gem. Luckily it does not have any extra dependencies.

Comment: after some research about DL on ruby 2.0 I found that it is deprecated and replaced with [fiddle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html), you would consider to use it rather than DL if you can't use FFI. Fiddle seems to be available for ruby 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 too (I updated the answer)

Comment: Oh, thanks for that information. Good to know, even the target platform is running the 1.9 version yet.

Comment: Now I can see the fiddle library is also included in the current patch level of 1.9 .